# Magento 2 | Component manager wont work after migration

Tags: magento2, migration, marketplace

I finally managed to migrate my Magento1 (1.9.1.0) to Magento 2 (2.1.3) with the Data-migration tool from Magento.

Everything went well, after a few mapping issues and fixes for that the migration went straight trough.

But as soon i want to install a few extensions from the marketplace and i have to enter the keys (public & private) to login into the account i get a never ending "Please wait" -popup. After closing and reloading the Web setup wizard the keys are saved but the extension grid wont show... just another neverending "Please wait..." popup.

Do you guys know anything about that ?

Do you guys know how to fix that ?

What i've already tried:

- Reindexing
- Cleaned cache
- Reloading the site and tried again

**Update:**

Found a warning when entering the component-manager page:

```
The specified value "{{currentPage}}" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?
```

Still cant figure out why i cant get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved**

Was an `vcs`-module wich wasnt configured correctly and by that it was conflicting with some Magento stuff.

After removing the module everything worked just fine again.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Can you explain how you re-configured the vcs-module (whatever that is)? Thanks!

Comment: i uninstalled the extension and asked the developer why and how this could happen. Can not remember the exact way of how i managed to resolve this. You should email the developer and ask for some help.

Comment: Which extension do you mean? I'm having the problem with a fresh installation of Magento 2.1.5 (and I *am* the developer!!)